# Как отобразить сферу с объектами в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть лист объектов с угловыми координатами (широта, долгота). Как мне можно показать их наглядно на форме? Пытался уже что то сделать с `ViewPort3D`, но там рисовать сферу придется по точкам и нормалям, а значит будет детализация.

Мне пока приходит в голову использовать `ListBox` с `Canvas` в качестве панели, где будет отрисован круг, на котором будут отображены проекции объектов (то есть псевдо-сфера). Для начала хочу просто отобразить сферу с меридианами, которую я смогу вращать. По идее все должно получиться, но я даже не знаю с чего мне начать.

UPD:

Если буду использовать `ListBox` или `Selector` для возможности выделения элементов, то что делать с индексами? Хотелось бы, чтобы была зависимость между индексами и координатами (ведь координаты - уникальный ключ). Так перебор элементов будет значительно быстрее. Ну допустим тип double я смогу привести к целому числу, умножив его на число с нужным количеством нулей (точность), но как быть со второй координатой. Их ведь две, а индекс один. Как создать коллекцию с двойным индексом?

Comment: Я бы использовал мощь OpenGL... Причем это будет еще и переносимый код.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, наверное так лучше. Но мне придется очень долго его осваивать. Неоправданно долго.

Answer (score 3):

Всё очень просто. Вам нужно перевести сферические координаты (широту, долготу  радиус) в трёхмерные. Затем умножением на матрицу поворота повернуть в нужное положение. Затем спроектировать на плоскость, отбросив одну координату, например, Y. При этом точки с положительной координатой Y находятся на противоположной стороне и их надо отбросить. Полученную картинку из квадрата `[-R, R]` линейно отобразите в квадрат координат экрана.

Для обработки выделения я обычно использую не индексы, а вот такую конструкцию:

VM:

```
class Objects : NotifyPropertyChangeImpl
{
    ObservableCollection<ObjectVM> All { get; private set; }

    // стандартное INPC-свойство
    ObjectVM selectedObject;
    public ObjectVM SelectedObject
    {
        get { return selectedObject; }
        set
        {
            if (value == selectedObject) return;
            value = selectedObject;
            NotifyPropertyChange();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding All}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Полезный совет. Посмотрите еще дополнение к вопросу (UPD) пожалуйста.

Comment: @iRumba: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Не знаю, отмечать ли как ответ. Вопрос то обширный, скорее всего будут дополнения к нему и, возможно, реализация от меня. Или таки разделить тему на подтемы? Как считаете?

Comment: @iRumba: Ну, вопрос ваш, вы хозяин :) Но обычно расширения укладывают в новый вопрос.